# Java (lwjgl) OpenGL clear screen completely

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to tell OpenGL at one point that it should reset everything that has been rendered to the screen and start, so to say, from the begining. I need a way to do this without destroying the display.

I have already tried to wrap the whole openGL rendering engine into a loop but restarting the loop seems not to solve the issue, despite starting from the beginning objects that have been rendered do not disapear.

Is there a way to tell openGL that it should just reset the whole rendering process and begin from zero again?

This is in my main class:

```
static RenderClass engine = new RenderClass();  

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {           
        engine.setDisplayMode(1224, 720, "RenderExample");
        engine.RunOpenGL();
    }
}
```

and this is in my engine class where I call the openGL Methods:

```
public void RunOpenGL()
{
    camera(0,0,0, 0);

    while(master == true)
    {       
        if(Display.isCloseRequested())
            { master = false; }

        if(render == true)
        { OpenGLRenderMethods(); } // This will initate all OpenGL Rendering Mechanics

        Display.update();
    }
    Display.destroy();
    Keyboard.destroy();
    Mouse.destroy();
}
```

I thought it might work when I would set render = false; and then set it to render = true; again, so the engine would reset all openGL rendering mechanics. Instead it seems to just repeat itself, which means everything that has been rendered as of now is still visible.

Hope you can help me out,
Sincere Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [glClear](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClear.xhtml)?

Comment: No, that's not doing anything.. I've found a way around it though.. now I'm facing other issues..

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone else faces the same problem, here's how I found a way around it:

If your Models can be transformed and you want to get rid of them simply reduce their scale to 0, before that you would have to save the properties of every model on a text file and generate them from there.

Now when you set everyting to 0 you simply tell the engine to render the objects with the properties stated in the text file.

If you were to delet an object from the text file its scale will not be updated and stays at zero which then gives the impression of deleting the object.

Thats my solution, I hope it'll help someone else too!
Kind Regards!